# How do I call the correct method from a child class in an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, parent-child

I'm not sure if this is allowed in C#, but I'm pretty sure I've done it in other languages before.

Let's say I have class, `Parent`, which has children `Child0` and `Child1`. I make an array of type `Parent` where `Array[0]` is of type `Child0` and `Array[1]` is of type `Child1`. In this scenario, how do I call the children's methods? When I type `Array[0].Method()`, it calls the `Parent` version of Method. How do I get it to call the `Child0` version of Method? Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the `virtual` and `override` keywords?  What have you tried?  Show the code for the classes so we can see what's causing the behavior.

Comment: If you create the object as a parent, it will only have access to the properties/methods that are in the parent.  You need to create the object as a child in order to call the child methods.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to declare Method as virtual in the base class:

```
public class Parent{
    public virtual void Method(){
    ...
    }
}
```

and override it in the heriting classes :

```
public class Child : Parent{
    public override void Method(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't really need a "standard" implementation in your Parent class, because all the inherithing classes have there own version, you can also set the method as abstract:

```
public class Parent{
    abstract public void Method();
}
```

Then you don't have the choice and all the classes that inherit from Parent will have to provide an implementation for Method, otherwise you'll have a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

if you make the parent method `virtual` you can override the base method in your child classes.

```
public class Human
{       
    // Virtual method 
    public virtual void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i am a human");
    }
}

public class Male: Human
{        
    // Override the virtual method 
    public override void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i am a male");
        base.Draw(); // --> This will access the Say() method from the 
       //parent class.           
    }
}
```

add them to the array: (altho i would personally use a `List<T>`)

```
 Human[] x = new Human[2];
 x[0] = new Human();
 x[1] = new Male();
```

print out results:

```
 foreach (var i in x)
 {
    i.Say();
 }
```

will print out

```
"i am a human" // --> (parent class implementation)    
"i am a male" // --> (child class implementation)
```